# File upload not uploaded to server folder

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my Controller:

```
        @RequestMapping(value={"/editbook.admin"}, method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String editBookSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute Book book,
    @RequestParam(value ="file", required=false) MultipartFile file,Model model,
    @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id,
    ) throws Exception {
    try {
        uploadFile(book, file);
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        log.error("Error editing", e);
    }

        return "editbook";
}

    String path = /assets/BookPDFs;

    private void uploadFile(Book book, MultipartFile file) throws java.io.IOException {
    String destinationDirectory = path + File.separator;
    String fileName = SecurityUtil.getSimpleAlphaNum(file.getOriginalFilename());
    File destination = new File(destinationDirectory + fileName);
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getInputStream(), destination);
    book.setName(fileName);
    BookBA.saveOrUpdate(book);
}
```

I did build a JSP file to upload file with some information from page1 using MVC

I wanna Add ability to download the file from page2.

page2 it's just displaying all the books I have in my table.

I did method (uploadFile) to set the name in bd from the file name that I want to upload it and call the save method to save it in DB.

I can't download the file from the page2 since the file didn't upload to the server folder.

when I'm debugging the value of destination is setting the path correctly.
destination = assets\BookPDFs\testFile.pdf

```
        File destination = new File(destinationDirectory + fileName);
```

How could I do this step?

Comment: `/asserst/BookPDFs` - maybe /assets/... ?

Comment: Yes, I just did mistake. that the Path I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just worked fine. The problem was is that the path is uploading the file to another.

So this code is working:

```
  String path = /assets/BookPDFs;

private void uploadFile(Book book, MultipartFile file) throws java.io.IOException {
String destinationDirectory = path + File.separator;
String fileName = SecurityUtil.getSimpleAlphaNum(file.getOriginalFilename());
File destination = new File(destinationDirectory + fileName);
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getInputStream(), destination);
book.setName(fileName);
BookBA.saveOrUpdate(book);
```

}